# How can I lock the dash-to-dock icons?

Tags: gnome-shell, ubuntu-dock, gnome-shell-extension, dash-to-dock

How can I lock the dash-to-dock icons in GNOME? I don't want users to move or delete icons.

Comment: Hi what's your OS? and are the num 0f applications constant or would you like to add them also after locking certain number of apps??

Comment: My O.S. is debian linux (testing). The applications are constant. I would like that the users can not be add, remove, or move the icons.

Comment: 0k..its possible.. can you provide the output of `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favourite-apps`

Answer (score 2):

***Tested in Ubuntu 18.04.3***

1. `sudo touch /etc/dconf/profile/user`
2. `sudo -H gedit /etc/dconf/profile/user` (change `gedit` if you use different editor)

   and paste below content

   ```
   user-db:user
   system-db:local
   ```
3. `sudo mkdir /etc/dconf/db/local.d`
4. `sudo touch /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-FA`
5. `sudo -H gedit /etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-FA` (change `gedit` if you use different editor)

   and paste below content [note that below favorite-apps are my own.. use `gsettings get org.gnome.shell favorite-apps` output in your case]

   ```
   [org/gnome/shell]
   favorite-apps=['chromium-browser.desktop', 'google-chrome.desktop', 'org.gnome.Nautilus.desktop', 'org.gnome.Software.desktop', 'audacious.desktop', 'mpv.desktop', 'spotify_spotify.desktop', 'org.gnome.Terminal.desktop', 'libreoffice-writer.desktop', 'gnome-calculator_gnome-calculator.desktop', 'libreoffice-calc.desktop', 'gnome-control-center.desktop', 'org.gnome.tweaks.desktop', 'firefox.desktop']
   ```
6. `sudo mkdir /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks`
7. `sudo touch /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00-FA`
8. `sudo -H gedit /etc/dconf/db/local.d/locks/00-FA` (change gedit if you use different editor)

   and paste the below content

   ```
   /org/gnome/shell/favorite-apps
   ```
9. `sudo dconf update`
10. Must logout and login back to see the change

Source: https://help.gnome.org/admin/system-admin-guide/stable/desktop-background.html.en

[image]

when ever you need to change the favorite-apps, you can edit the file `/etc/dconf/db/local.d/00-FA` and run `sudo dconf update` then logout & login