# How to lock position of apps on the dock?

Tags: 18.04, dock

Is there a way to lock the position of apps on the dock? Currently, it is possible to shift them around by dragging them, but this has become annoying as I often drag them by accident. I've looked in the settings and in the GNOME tweaks application, but have been unsuccessful in finding a setting relevant to this behavior. Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1183117/739431 may be relateD

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I lock the dash-to-dock icons?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1183117/how-can-i-lock-the-dash-to-dock-icons)

Comment: @danzel Partly, thanks, but I'd prefer not to be able to drag the icons at all, rather than being able to drag them but not shift their position which is what the solution to that question results in.